# How do I initiate Bootstrap Spinner on button and return to original state when data is returned to AJAX?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap button that submit a form using jQuery AJAX, and return json values, and I need to change the button to a spinner and disable it when clicked and then return button to original state when the json data has been returned.

I have tried to initiate this on submit in the jQuery, but I am unable to get it to change the button, and I get no errors in the console.

My code I have so far :

```js
  $(function() {
    var id = '1';
    $('#SharedMailGroupForm' + id).submit(function() {
      $("#SharedMailUpdateButton").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#SharedMailUpdateButton").html(
        `<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>`
      );
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(jsonData) {
        // this is the callback, do all the work that depends on `jsonData` in here
        $('#SharedMailGroupColumn' + id).fadeIn("slow").removeClass("HiddenDIV");
        console.log(jsonData.Value1);
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#SharedMailGroupColumn' + id).fadeIn("slow").addClass("HiddenDIV");
        }, 10000);
        $('#SharedMailGroupText' + id).html(jsonData.Value1);
      }, "json");
      $("#SharedMailUpdateButton").html(
        `<span><i class="far fa-save"></span>`
      );
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group-append">
  <button id="SharedMailUpdateButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="SharedMailGroupForm1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Gem Shared Mail Grupper"><span>Save</span></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, move this line `$("#SharedMailUpdateButton").html(<span>><i class="far fa-save">...` after `$('#SharedMailGroupText' + id).html(jsonData.Value1);` line .

Comment: Hi @Swati .. Great that will propably work when I get the spinner initiated, but at this point the button does not start the spinner when clicked .. any suggestions?

Comment: Swati has already pointed this out the problem.  Your spinner does actually start, but it is immediately removed.  The callback happens asynchronously, but the rest of your code - including the line which reverts your button back to default state - does not.  It means that milliseconds after you show your spinner it is removed again, too fast to notice.  If you remove the spinner from within the callback, which won't happen until the AJAX is done, you'll see it.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct my bad ;-( .. @Swati, thank you .. please post an answer and I will contribute you :-)

Comment: No worries it was just a typo no need to answer .But ,feel free to answer you own question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Swati and @Don't Panic the issue was quite simple to solve by moving line `$("#SharedMailUpdateButton").html(<span>><i class="far fa-save">` after `$('#SharedMailGroupText' + id).html(jsonData.Value1);` .. Thanks guys :-)